# Digisector DS-69 video digitizer

Tags: color-computer

The DS-69 was a cartridge you could plug into the computer to digitize a composite video source. It fully supported writing images to floppy disks.

Can the DS-69 (A or B) be used with Y-Cable?

The manual only mentions using the device with a Multi-Pak, or other "active" switcher.

Answer (score 4):

The manual asks for a "tee" connector - that's a simple wire connection without any logic inside (and equivalent to monitor passthrough that's also supported).

You can safely use an Y-cable instead.